# SQL database backup with entity framework 6

Tags: c#, sql

```
string dbname = _dbContext.Database.Connection.Database;

const string sqlCommand = @"BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO  DISK = N'{1}' WITH NOFORMAT,
    NOINIT,  NAME = N'MajesticDb-Ali-Full Database Backup',
    SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";

int path = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior
    .DoNotEnsureTransaction,
    string.Format(sqlCommand, dbname, "MajesticDB"));
```

I am using this code to make a database backup. It's working fine but this code is replacing the previous file with the new one. How do I change it so it doesn't?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you overwriting db backup with the same name?

Comment: Yes its overwriting. I want to save new one every time

Comment: @RanaAli Add datetime with your db name.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
string dbname = _dbContext.Database.Connection.Database;
string dbBackUp= "MajesticDB" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
const string sqlCommand = @"BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO  DISK = N'{1}' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MajesticDb-Ali-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
int path= _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, string.Format(sqlCommand, dbname , dbBackUp));
```

Comment: This line is incorrect `int path= _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, string.Format(sqlCommand, dbBackUp, "MajesticDB"));`

Comment: I think you meant to put `dbBackUp` and not `"MajesticDB"`, since at the moment you are not renaming your database backup

Comment: @Draken Edit done. Typing mistake thanks for noticing. Sorry for late reply and edit.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
string backupname= "MajesticDB" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
 const string sqlCommand = @"BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO  DISK = N'{1}' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MajesticDb-Ali-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
       int path= _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, string.Format(sqlCommand, dbname, backupname));
```

this way, to backup name "MajesticDB" is appended date and time, so every time you call your backup procedure, database will be backed up with different name.